# Host OWIN web app on random port

Tags: c#, owin

Is it possible to host an OWIN web app (via `WebApp.Start()` or some other method) on a random port. I've looked at solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978040/789683) (1) which use `TcpListener` to find a random port, or progressive scanning techniques like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223188/789683) (2), but it would be great if you could just do something like `WebApp.Start("http://localhost:0")` and be able to inspect the actual port binding.

To clarify: my issue with (1) is that the port is bound, then released, then rebound by the `WebApp.Start` method, and the second binding may fail inbetween (i.e. race condition). My issue with (2) is the potential inefficiency (although I have nothing to base this gut feeling on)

Comment: #2 is likely going to take some amount of time on the order of milliseconds. Do you really restart this app so often that performance here is an issue? If you do, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: so your question is how to host an OWIN web app on a random port or how to detect if there is a running service on a given port? :-)