# How Do I Sign In To Google with CEFSharp Browser in WPF?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, cefsharp

I know this is a very basic question, but I'm creating a browser in wpf (I'm almost done with it) using CEFSharp, but I hit a snag with logging into google on some accounts. I get a **"This browser or app may not be secure."** message. Now, I've researched using OAuth to get a token for accessing and using certain features of Google, but not just how to log in as a whole. I just want the user to be able to log into Google, just like they would on a Chrome browser (without the Sync option, of course).

[image]
[image]
[image]

I registered my application with Google Console, and received a ClientId and ClientSecret, and I created a window to be called when the sign-in button is clicked on the google page that tries to get the token, but when the user types in their e-mail, they get the same message (See Below).

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure if there's an API that I can use or something that can let my user login to google through my browser without having to call the Google Chrome browser itself, because that defeats the purpose of my browser being self-sufficient. I've been beating my head on this for days. Can anyone help?

Below is the xaml for my Google Login window:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Windows.GoogleLoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NP_Browser.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Google Login Window" Height="450" Width="800" Icon="../Images/NPBrowserLogo.ico">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btv" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Visibility="{Binding State.IsSigned, Converter={StaticResource btv}}">
        <Label Content="{Binding State.Token.Name}" />
    </DockPanel>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding State.IsNotSigned, Converter={StaticResource btv}}">
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="Wb" FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Below is the code-behind for my Google Login window:

```
namespace MyProject.Windows
```

{
public partial class GoogleLoginWindow : Window
{
public GoogleLoginWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
State = new OAuthState();
DataContext = this;
Topmost = true;
var thread = new Thread(HandleRedirect);
thread.Start();
}

```
    public OAuthState State { get; }

    private async void HandleRedirect()
    {
        State.Token = null;

        var request = OAuthRequest.BuildLoopbackRequest();
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(request.RedirectUri);
        listener.Start();

        // note: add a reference to System.Windows.Presentation and a 'using System.Windows.Threading' for this to compile
        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Wb.Address = request.AuthorizationRequestUri;
        });

        // here, we'll wait for redirection from our hosted webbrowser
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();

        // browser has navigated to our small http server answer anything here
        string html = string.Format("<html><body></body></html>");
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        var stream = context.Response.OutputStream;
        var responseTask = stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            stream.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        });

        string error = context.Request.QueryString["error"];
        if (error != null)
            return;

        string state = context.Request.QueryString["state"];
        if (state != request.State)
            return;

        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
        State.Token = request.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code);
    }
}

// state model
public class OAuthState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private OAuthToken _token;
    public OAuthToken Token
    {
        get => _token;
        set
        {
            if (_token == value)
                return;

            _token = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Token)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSigned)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsNotSigned)));
        }
    }

    public bool IsSigned => Token != null && Token.ExpirationDate > DateTime.Now;
    public bool IsNotSigned => !IsSigned;
}

// This is a sample. Fille information (email, etc.) can depend on scopes
[DataContract]
public class OAuthToken
{
    [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Locale { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Profile { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string[] Scopes { get; set; }

    // not from google's response, but we store this
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}

// largely inspired from
// https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows
public sealed class OAuthRequest
{
    private const string ClientId = "My-Client-Id";
    private const string ClientSecret = "My-Client-Secret";

    private const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";

    private OAuthRequest()
    {
    }

    public string AuthorizationRequestUri { get; private set; }
    public string State { get; private set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; private set; }
    public string CodeVerifier { get; private set; }
    public string[] Scopes { get; private set; }

    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp
    public static OAuthRequest BuildLoopbackRequest(params string[] scopes)
    {
        var request = new OAuthRequest
        {
            CodeVerifier = RandomDataBase64Url(32),
            Scopes = scopes
        };

        string codeChallenge = Base64UrlEncodeNoPadding(Sha256(request.CodeVerifier));
        const string codeChallengeMethod = "S256";

        string scope = BuildScopes(scopes);

        request.RedirectUri = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, GetRandomUnusedPort());
        request.State = RandomDataBase64Url(32);
        request.AuthorizationRequestUri = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile{6}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
            AuthorizationEndpoint,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(request.RedirectUri),
            ClientId,
            request.State,
            codeChallenge,
            codeChallengeMethod,
            scope);

        return request;
    }

    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp Step 5: Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens
    public OAuthToken ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(string code)
    {
        if (code == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(code));

        string tokenRequestBody = string.Format("code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&code_verifier={3}&client_secret={4}&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code",
            code,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(RedirectUri),
            ClientId,
            CodeVerifier,
            ClientSecret
            );

        return TokenRequest(tokenRequestBody, Scopes);
    }

    // this is not used in this sample, but can be used to refresh a token from an old one
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp Refreshing an access token
    public OAuthToken Refresh(OAuthToken oldToken)
    {
        if (oldToken == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(oldToken));

        string tokenRequestBody = string.Format("refresh_token={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&grant_type=refresh_token",
            oldToken.RefreshToken,
            ClientId,
            ClientSecret
            );

        return TokenRequest(tokenRequestBody, oldToken.Scopes);
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
            return default(T);

        return Deserialize<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] json)
    {
        if (json == null || json.Length == 0)
            return default(T);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(json))
        {
            return Deserialize<T>(ms);
        }
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(Stream json)
    {
        if (json == null)
            return default(T);

        var ser = CreateSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.ReadObject(json);
    }

    private static DataContractJsonSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK")
        };
        return new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, settings);
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223063/how-can-i-create-an-httplistener-class-on-a-random-port-in-c/
    private static int GetRandomUnusedPort()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        listener.Start();
        var port = ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        listener.Stop();
        return port;
    }

    private static string RandomDataBase64Url(int length)
    {
        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            rng.GetBytes(bytes);
            return Base64UrlEncodeNoPadding(bytes);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Sha256(string text)
    {
        using (var sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            return sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));
        }
    }

    private static string Base64UrlEncodeNoPadding(byte[] buffer)
    {
        string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        // converts base64 to base64url.
        b64 = b64.Replace('+', '-');
        b64 = b64.Replace('/', '_');
        // strips padding.
        b64 = b64.Replace("=", "");
        return b64;
    }

    private static OAuthToken TokenRequest(string tokenRequestBody, string[] scopes)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TokenEndpoint);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenRequestBody);
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var token = Deserialize<OAuthToken>(responseStream);
            token.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 0, token.ExpiresIn);
            var user = GetUserInfo(token.AccessToken);
            token.Name = user.Name;
            token.Picture = user.Picture;
            token.Email = user.Email;
            token.Locale = user.Locale;
            token.FamilyName = user.FamilyName;
            token.GivenName = user.GivenName;
            token.Id = user.Id;
            token.Profile = user.Profile;
            token.Scopes = scopes;
            return token;
        }
    }

    private static UserInfo GetUserInfo(string accessToken)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UserInfoEndpoint);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", accessToken));
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return Deserialize<UserInfo>(stream);
        }
    }

    private static string BuildScopes(string[] scopes)
    {
        string scope = null;
        if (scopes != null)
        {
            foreach (var sc in scopes)
            {
                scope += "%20" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sc);
            }
        }
        return scope;
    }

    // https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/openidconnect/getOpenIdConnect
    [DataContract]
    private class UserInfo
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "kind")]
        public string Kind { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "picture")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "locale")]
        public string Locale { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "family_name")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "given_name")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "sub")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "profile")]
        public string Profile { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Far as I know it's not possible to do this with `OATH` even though `Google` suggests it is. See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16764 and https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16717 Far as I know `Google` haven't provided an official method of logging in yet, people have listed some workarounds. I'd suggest if you have further questions discussing on `ceforum`.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/embedder-dev/STyM5ZNTHMM/POj1v_cqBgAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to login on a web view and [Google blocks that](https://auth0.com/blog/google-blocks-oauth-requests-from-embedded-browsers/).
Unfortunately, OAuth for desktop apps is tricky. I have some [visual blog posts](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/) and a code sample you can run to understand behaviour:

- Login by invoking the system browser
- Receive the response by spinning up a loopback web server
- Or receive the response via a private URI scheme (my preference)

My samples are coded in Electron / Javascript. However, the below C# code samples accompany the IdentityModel security library, and I would recommend using this library for your app:

- [Loopback Sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/ConsoleSystemBrowser)
- [Private Scheme Sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WindowsConsoleSystemBrowser)

Comment: Have you been successful in logging to Gmail with oauth specifically?

Comment: Both the Loopback Sample and Private Scheme Sample links go to "404 Page Not Found" for me. Do you have any better links?

Comment: Oops - fixed up the above links

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line :

```
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 /CefSharp Browser" + Cef.CefSharpVersion;
```

after `CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();`

Answer (score 0):

Google Blocked logins to it from embedded browser as an act against Man In The Middle Attacks.