# Google signin on cefsharp c#

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how to let users signin with Google on cefsharp.winforms c# because anytime i try it says "this browser or app may not be secure". If there is an alternative let me know.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Try setting the User-agent to a well-known one (FireFox, Chrome...).

Comment: See this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506808/how-do-i-sign-in-to-google-with-cefsharp-browser-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try add this line :**

```cs
CefSettings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 CefSharp Browser/" + Cef.CefSharpVersion;
```

**after `CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();`**

---