# How to pass UserInfo from Google OAuth to Requesting Website in WPF CefSharp Browser

Tags: wpf, google-oauth, cefsharp

So here's the question. I have a browser that I'm developing using CefSharp, and I'm trying to get the browser to properly authenticate and pass the UserInfo back to the website that's requesting a login. Below is the button that they are clicking on the website:

[image]

As it is written now, I catch this login event in the PopUpHandler class which implements the ILifeSpanHandler interface. I catch it specifically in the OnBeforePopup method, and run the default OAuth class that I got off of the internet. I've modified the OAuth class a bit to implement a custom cefsharp browser pop-up to get the user to input their credentials.

```
public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName,
        WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo,
        IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {

        foreach (var allowedSite in Helper.AllowedPopups)
        {
            if (targetUrl.Contains(allowedSite))
            {
                if (targetUrl.Contains("login") && targetUrl.Contains("oauth"))
                {
                    OAuth that = new OAuth();
                    that.AuthorizeWithGoogle();
                    newBrowser = null;
                    return true;
                }

                Helper.OpenNewTab(targetUrl, true);
                newBrowser = null;
                return true;
            }
        }

        string askingURL = Helper.GetWebsiteName(targetUrl);

        AllowPopUpNotifier allowThis = new AllowPopUpNotifier(askingURL);
        if (allowThis.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Helper.AllowedPopups.Add(askingURL);
            if (targetUrl.Contains("login") && targetUrl.Contains("oauth"))
            {
                var newPopUpWindow = new CustomPopUpWindow(targetUrl);
                newPopUpWindow.Show();
                newBrowser = null;
                return true;
            }

            Helper.OpenNewTab(targetUrl, true);
            newBrowser = null;
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            newBrowser = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then, the OAuth class that I've implemented looks like this:

```
   public class OAuth
{
    //client configuration;
    const string clientID = "581786658708-elflankerquo1a6vsckabbhn25hclla0.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const string clientSecret = "3f6NggMbPtrmIBpgx-MK2xXK";
    //const string clientID = "1020802206989-hsvquqebqgrj8kj4b387lcnosos4manc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    //const string clientSecret = "5k_uICJwwq25oV6-BM22310V";
    const string authorizationEndpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
    const string tokenEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    const string userInfoEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";

    //ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/3978040
    public static int GetRandomUnusedPort()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        listener.Start();
        var port = ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        listener.Stop();
        return port;
    }

    public async Task<UserCredential> getUserCredential()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        string[] scopes = new string[] { }; // user basic profile

        //Read client id and client secret from Web config file

        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "1020802206989-hsvquqebqgrj8kj4b387lcnosos4manc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "3f6NggMbPtrmIBpgx-MK2xXK"
            }, scopes,
            "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Auth.Api.Store"));

        return credential;
    }

    public async void AuthorizeWithGoogle()
    {
        //Generates state and PKCE values.
        string state = randomDataBase64url(32);
        string code_verifier = randomDataBase64url(32);
        string code_challenge = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier));
        const string code_challenge_method = "S256";

        //Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
        string redirectURI = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, GetRandomUnusedPort());
        Debug.WriteLine("redirect URI: " + redirectURI);

        //Creates an HttpListener to listen for requests on that redirect URI.

       var http = new HttpListener();
        http.Prefixes.Add(redirectURI);
        Debug.WriteLine("Listening..");
        http.Start();

        //Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
        string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
            authorizationEndpoint,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
            clientID,
            state,
            code_challenge,
            code_challenge_method);

        //Opens request in the browser.
        //Process.Start(authorizationRequest);
        //var newBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        var that = new CustomPopUpWindow(authorizationRequest);
        //that.browser.Address = authorizationRequest;
        //newBrowser.Source = new Uri(authorizationRequest, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //newBrowser.Load(authorizationRequest);
        //that.Content = newBrowser;
        that.Show();

        //Waits for the OAuth authorization response.

       var context = await http.GetContextAsync();

        // Brings this app back to the foreground.
        var mainWindow = Helper.GetMainWindow();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            mainWindow.Activate();
        });

        //Sends an HTTP response to the browser.
        var response = context.Response;
        string responseString = string.Format("<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=https://google.com'></head><body>Please return to the app.</body></html>");
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        var responseOutput = response.OutputStream;
        Task responseTask = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            responseOutput.Close();
            http.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
        });

        //Checks for errors.
        if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("error") != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("OAuth authorization error: {0}.", context.Request.QueryString.Get("error")));
                Helper.GoogleAuthorized = false;
                CustomMessageBox.Show("Google login not authorized. Check your login credentials and try again.");
                return;
            }
        if (context.Request.QueryString.Get("code") == null
            || context.Request.QueryString.Get("state") == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Malformed authorization response. " + context.Request.QueryString);
            Helper.GoogleAuthorized = false;
            CustomMessageBox.Show("Google login not authorized. Check your login credentials and try again.");
            return;
        }

        //extracts the code
       var code = context.Request.QueryString.Get("code");
        var incoming_state = context.Request.QueryString.Get("state");

        //Compares the receieved state to the expected value, to ensure that
        //this app made the request which resulted in authorization.
        if (incoming_state != state)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Received request with invalid state ({0})", incoming_state));
            Helper.GoogleAuthorized = false;
            CustomMessageBox.Show("Google login not authorized. Check your login credentials and try again.");
            return;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Authorization code: " + code);

        //Starts the code exchange at the Token Endpoint.
        performCodeExchange(code, code_verifier, redirectURI);

    }

    async void performCodeExchange(string code, string code_verifier, string redirectURI)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exchanging code for tokens...");

        //builds the  request
        string tokenRequestURI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
        string tokenRequestBody = string.Format("code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&code_verifier={3}&client_secret={4}&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code",
            code,
            System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
            clientID,
            code_verifier,
            clientSecret
            );

       //sends the request
       HttpWebRequest tokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tokenRequestURI);
        tokenRequest.Method = "POST";
        tokenRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        tokenRequest.Accept = "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        byte[] _byteVersion = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenRequestBody);
        tokenRequest.ContentLength = _byteVersion.Length;
        Stream stream = tokenRequest.GetRequestStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(_byteVersion, 0, _byteVersion.Length);
        stream.Close();

        try
        {
           //gets the response
           WebResponse tokenResponse = await tokenRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tokenResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                //reads response body
                string responseText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(responseText);

                //converts to dictionary
                Dictionary<string, string> tokenEndpointDecoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseText);

                string access_token = tokenEndpointDecoded["access_token"];
                userinfoCall(access_token);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("HTTP: " + response.StatusCode);
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        //reads response body
                        string responseText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine(responseText);

                        Helper.GoogleAuthorized = false;
                        CustomMessageBox.Show("Google login not authorized. Check your login credentials and try again.");
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


    async void userinfoCall(string access_token)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Making API Call to Userinfo...");

        //builds the  request
        string userinfoRequestURI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";

       //sends the request
       HttpWebRequest userinfoRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userinfoRequestURI);
        userinfoRequest.Method = "GET";
        userinfoRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", access_token));
        userinfoRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        userinfoRequest.Accept = "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        //gets the response
       WebResponse userinfoResponse = await userinfoRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        using (StreamReader userinfoResponseReader = new StreamReader(userinfoResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //reads response body
            string userinfoResponseText = await userinfoResponseReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(userinfoResponseText);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Appends the given string to the on-screen log, and the debug console.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "output" > string to be appended</param>
    public void output(string output)
    {
        //textBoxOutput.Text = textBoxOutput.Text + output + Environment.NewLine;
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns URI-safe data with a given input length.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "length" > Input length(nb.output will be longer)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string randomDataBase64url(uint length)
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        return base64urlencodeNoPadding(bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the SHA256 hash of the input string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "inputStirng" ></ param >
    /// < returns ></ returns >
    public static byte[] sha256(string inputStirng)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputStirng);
        SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        return sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Base64url no-padding encodes the given input buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "buffer" ></ param >
    /// < returns ></ returns >
    public static string base64urlencodeNoPadding(byte[] buffer)
    {
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        //Converts base64 to base64url.
        base64 = base64.Replace("+", "-");
        base64 = base64.Replace("/", "_");
        //Strips padding.
        base64 = base64.Replace("=", "");

        return base64;
    }

}
```

}

This gets me the UserInfo, and writes it on the "Debug.WriteLine(userinfoResponseText);" line in the OAuth class. However, I don't know how to redirect it back to the website that initially called the pop-up. Can anybody help? I'm so lost.

Comment: I don't believe Google allows oauth logins for any of their apps, just their services that provide APIs.

Comment: You can open DevTools in Chrome to look at the requests/response JavaScript to see how it behaves normally.

Comment: There's gotta be a way. The login sends an auth token from the website, and returns user information. I just have to pass that back to the website...

Comment: Doesn't mean it's the same with token. You'll have to dig into it yourself.